# Adding a book object to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a BookStore class which uses some objects in my existing book class and author class. Now I have an empty arraylist that needs to be filled. The question says I must do this in the BookStore class not in the test class. How do I add a book object in to this arraylist?  It then says I should write a method to get books. I am not sure what I should do next on this and I have searched a lot but still no finding anything similar to what I have.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BookStore
{
   //we will store Book object references in this 
   private ArrayList<Book> books;


   /*NB: Our reference (books) doesn't refer to anything
   **when it is declared so our default constructor
   **makes it refer to an empty arraylist*/
   public BookStore()
   {
      books = new ArrayList<Book>();
   }

   public void addBook(Book bookToAdd) 
   {
      ArrayList<Book> Book1 = new ArrayList<Book>();
      if (bookToAdd != null) 
      {  
         int noOfBooks = 0;
         noOfBooks++; //increasing this counter                
      }// end if
   } // end addBook
}
```

Comment: `books.add(bookToAdd);`

Comment: You should use the member class `books`, not creating a new one inside the method (its scope is limited to the method).

Then you simply provide a mutators for your class (getters and setters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `add` method to add the book to the list:

```
public void addBook(Book bookToAdd) {
    books.add(bookToAdd);
}
```

And don't use `noOfBooks` to count the number of books.
You already have this information in the `books` array list itself, see `books.size()`.

And don't call this method with a `null` parameter.
It just doesn't make sense to a "null" book.
You might want to throw an exception in this case to alert the caller that he's doing something strange, for example:

```
public void addBook(Book bookToAdd) {
    if (bookToAdd == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The book to add should not be null");
    }
    books.add(bookToAdd);
}
```